# fscrawler get extracted text in restapi response

Tags: elasticsearch, fscrawler

I implemented fscrawler with elasticsearch.
Rest is enabled.
I can post a file to fscrawler and the text is correctly extracted and put in the elasticsearch index.
I can verify that with Kibana.

I m not able to get the extracted text in the response.

I tried several setups in the _settings.yaml.
But i don't get the text back in the reponse, unless i add debug=true as queryParam calling fscrawler endpoint.

```
http://localhost:8080/_document?debug=true
```

The endpoint is called directly with postman.

Here is my _settings.yaml

```
---
name: "idx"
fs:
  indexed_chars: 100%
  lang_detect: true
  continue_on_error: true
  logging: ERROR

  ocr:
    language: "eng"
    enabled: true
    pdf_strategy: "auto"
elasticsearch:
  nodes:
    - url: "https://elasticsearch:9200"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "Test123"
  ssl_verification: false
  store_source: true
  index_content: true
rest :
  url: "http://fscrawler:8080"
```

my fscrawler image:

```
dadoonet/fscrawler:2.10-SNAPSHOT
```

Elasticstackversion: 8.6.2

response:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "filename": "JAVASCRIPT.pdf",
    "url": "https://elasticsearch:9200/idx/_doc/337d3e366ce4b765f650c5a87011e117"
}
```

I found no way to get the extracted text in the response, unless as i mentioned setting ?debug=true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either call Elasticsearch to get the indexed document:

```
curl https://localhost:9200/idx/_doc/337d3e366ce4b765f650c5a87011e117
```

Or call the [simulate API](https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin/fs/rest.html#simulate-upload) of fscrawler.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I needed it to be indexed also, simulateapi doesnt do that. So it seems to me that both returned text and indexed is only possible with debug=true. I want avoid to call again elasticsearch to get the text.

Comment: Right. You need to call Elasticsearch. A GET by id should be super fast.

Comment: The only way today is indeed to use debug=true.